# SSML could not be parsed in Actions on Google with UTF-8 encoding

Tags: java, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I tried with SSML output with the TTS simulator and it works find. However, I got the error when I return the same SSML output from my fulfillment backend.

```
MalformedResponse at expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[0].simple_response: 'ssml' could not be parsed
```

My backend fulfillment encodes the output in UTF-8 and as a result, the output encodes the < to \u003c and the > to \u003d, making every thing failed.

Raw Response captured from Logs Explorer:

```
{
    "simpleResponse": {
        "displayText":"星級導師 - Zoe",
        "ssml":"\u003cspeak\u003e 星級導師 - Zoe \u003cbreak time\u003d\u00271\u0027 /\u003e \u003c/speak\u003e  \u003cspeak\u003e    \u003cp\u003e        \u003cs\u003e香港中文大學體育運動科學系理學碩士學生，Zolar Fitness 創辦人，健身教練。由肥妹變成健身室老闆，致力推動健康資訊給香港人。\u003c/s\u003e    \u003c/p\u003e\u003c/speak\u003e"
    }
}
```

Does Actions on Google accepts the UTF-8 encoding for fulfillment response? Or shall I encode my response with other encoding?

(2020/12/03 Updates)

If the textToSpeech component is included, no this error message appears.

```
{
    "simpleResponse": {
        "displayText":"星級導師 - Zoe",
        "ssml":"\u003cspeak\u003e 星級導師 - Zoe \u003cbreak time\u003d\u00271\u0027 /\u003e \u003c/speak\u003e  \u003cspeak\u003e    \u003cp\u003e        \u003cs\u003e香港中文大學體育運動科學系理學碩士學生，Zolar Fitness 創辦人，健身教練。由肥妹變成健身室老闆，致力推動健康資訊給香港人。\u003c/s\u003e    \u003c/p\u003e\u003c/speak\u003e",
        "textToSpeech":"\u003cspeak\u003e 星級導師 - Zoe \u003cbreak time\u003d\u00271\u0027 /\u003e \u003c/speak\u003e  \u003cspeak\u003e    \u003cp\u003e        \u003cs\u003e香港中文大學體育運動科學系理學碩士學生，Zolar Fitness 創辦人，健身教練。由肥妹變成健身室老闆，致力推動健康資訊給香港人。\u003c/s\u003e    \u003c/p\u003e\u003c/speak\u003e"
    }
}
```

Comment: The malformed problem has been resolved. But the TTS engine could not say the words properly.

SSML tags are read out instead of processed.

Comment: Can you share the current raw response that isn't malformed? So I can see how the response looks to better understand the problem

Comment: @mandychannyc The response has included the textToSpeech

Comment: @mandychannyc Actually I got the error message again even if I had the ssml and textToSpeech component. But I couldn't post the raw response here